# UILabel setting x,y co-ordinates programmatically

Tags: xcode, uilabel

How to `position (x, y)` a `UILabel` programmatically within a view, preferably from `viewDidLoad`? The `label` has an `Outlet` for it, e.g. `myLabel`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here you can adjust the position of `UILabel`.
In `viewWillAppear` method you just need to change the origin of UILabel as below.

```
     CGRect frame = myLabel.frame;
     frame.origin.y=10;//pass the Y cordinate 
     frame.origin.x= 12;//pass the X cordinate
     myLabel.frame= frame;
```

I hope it clears you.

Comment: Clear indeed, just what was required. Many thanks. I suspect that appraoch will unlock some other log jams I'm having.

Answer (score 7):

```
[label setFrame:CGRectMake(10,20,100,200)];
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of setting the frame you can use just `setCenter(x, y)`.

Eg: `myLabel.center = CGPointMake(x,y);`.

Here you just need to pass the points at where you want to put `UIlabel` inside the `UIView`.

Comment: Swift: myLabel.center = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)